# How to export my azure machine learning model to json

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-machine-learning-service

I wonder if it's possible to export my model to a json file, so I can do some kind of versioning.

Building up a model with Azure Machine Learning Studio is easy, but I need to save the previous version anytime I do an update.

It's possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure ML Studio, the versioning is available as Run History: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/manage-experiment-iterations
Regards,
Jaya